# Shipping Adjustment not being added to Total Price

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, shipping, adjusters

I have an adjuster that calculates shipping cost which I can see when I view the order in the backend. The problem is that the shipping adjustment is not being added to the total price. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was another plugin interfering with the order total.